# Removed startup applications reappear after logout

Tags: gnome, startup-applications

I have noticed something weird and annoying as soon as I switched to Ubuntu Desktop 22.04:
One of my post-installation procedures, which I run after installing a vanilla desktop, is to remove unwanted default startup applications.
I use both the `Startup Applications` app and the relevant section in the  `Gnome Tweak Tool`. The weird annoying thing is, as soon as I log out and log back in again, or reboot the machine - the applications I've just removed *reappear*, as if I didn't remove them at all...
The only work around I found is to delete the apps's `.desktop` file from `/usr/share/applications`, something I rather **not** to do.

Can someone point me to any relevant documentation regarding this, any tips on how to do it the right way are greatly appreciated.

Thank you!

Comment: You mention "*remove unwanted default startup applications*" but don't tell us what applications you removed so we can look for clues.  I'm not sure I understand what you're asking (*thus could be my own misunderstanding as I'm not a big GNOME user*), but giving an example of the applications you mean, may help us to understand & better respond.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Deleting them from startup applications doesn't help if `/usr/share/applications/` has a desktop file that has autostart on by default.

You can mask those by creating your own desktop file for them in `~/.config/autostart/`.   It is unfortunate gnome tweak tool doesn't do this for you.

Additional applications (which are ignored by gnome tweak tool) may be started by systemd and can be listed with `systemctl --user list-unit-files`